# Создание консольного сервера для отслеживания действий (событий)

Tags: c#

Прошу натолкнуть, подсказать или объяснить как его сделать. Имеется приложение на WPF, C# с БД MSSQL посредством EntityFramework. Нужно реализовать консольный LocalHost, чтобы прослеживалось в консоли запуск приложения (т.е генерировался его Id, например) и, соответственно завершение работы приложения. Ну и ещё чтобы при нажатии кнопки в конечном окне в консоль сервера передавался id билета, который уже в программе генерируется, просто передавался в консоль.

Comment: Как я понял "сценарий использования", это примерно что то такое: есть компьютерный класс. На рабочих местах ученики запускают программу - "экзаменатор". При этом на рабочемм месте учителя долден появиться в консоли сигнал о том, что на таком то компе программа запущена. Далее - при нажатиив  программе кнопки - в консоли тоже появляется об этом сообщение. Так? Тогда для такого напрашивается то, что называется "сервер очередей". Например, rabbit mq. Это решение, которое не требует модификации базы данных. А так - можно было бы в базе данных еще одну табличку сделать и обновлять данные через неё.

Comment: чем-то напоминает логирование. Используйте его и выкидывайте в консоль/файл/поток ... сообщения.

Comment: Не надо изобретать велосипеды. Создаете под каждого клиента свою учетную запись на сервере MSSQL и запись в лог-таблицу событий сессии работы того или иного клиента.

Comment: @Bulson, это дипломный проект, который задумывается а-ля для терминальных компьютеров, смысла делать для каждого учётку не вижу.

Comment: @S.H., для чего мне с бд взаимодействовать, прочтите комментарий выше, я немного пояснил что это и для чего)
Ну а так да, Вы правильно поняли как должно работать.